# grep recursively backwards

Tags: grep

How do I grep recusively backwards.
Let's say I have the following folders:

```
20170808
20170809
20170810
```

When I do `grep -ri 'string'` grep takes each folder in alphabetical order and searches for 'string'. How do I make it go backwards, from the last one to the first?

Answer (score 2):

The order for `grep -r` will generally be random (not necessarily alphabetical), typically based on how the files are arranged in the directory and what possible re-ordering your `grep` implementation may do to optimise the directory traversal.

Here, with GNU `grep` 2.25:

```
$ grep -r . .
./4/c:c
./1/b:b
./2/a:a
./10/d:d
```

If you want a specific order, you have to give up on `-r` and give the list of files as arguments in the order you want.

For instance, in your case, and using `zsh`:

```
$ grep -H . ./**/*(D.On)
./4/c:c
./2/a:a
./1/b:b
./10/d:d
```

Here using `On` for reverse order *by name*. You can add the `n` qualifier for numeric sort:

```
$ grep -H . ./**/*(D.nOn)
./10/d:d
./4/c:c
./2/a:a
./1/b:b
```

(`-H` being another GNU `grep` extension to ensure the file name is always printed even if there's only one file. With other `grep` implementation, you can add an extra empty file as argument like `/dev/null` to make sure `grep` is passed at least two file names).

That is also very useful to `zgrep` *rotated* log files in chronological order (like `access.log.10.gz` ... `access.log.2.gz`, `access.log.1`, `access.log`) with:

```
zgrep something access.log*(nOn)
```

(though you can also sort by *last modification time* with `zgrep something access.log*(Om)` if those can be relied upon).